# Integer Count Python using Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

How can I make a **recursive** **function** that determines whether an integer `x` is part of an integer `y`? For instance, the function will return `True` if we input `(1234, 23)` and `False` if we input `(76384, 44)`. `x` can also only be a two-digit positive number.
I already did the last condition:

```
def intCheck(y, x):
    if x < 10 or x > 99:
        return "invalid"
```

But I don't know how to do the main part of the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just to clarify, your explanation says "x in y" but it seems like your example is "y in x". Does the run of numbers need to be contiguous (said differently, is `12` in `132` OK)? For the record, recursion is a horrible solution to this problem. Your teacher is telling you to hammer a nail and giving you a feather, a hairpin and a pipe cleaner to do it with. You can just use `str(x) in str(y)`, so don't let your teacher get in the way of your education.

Comment: Hi! In my examples, I used `(y, x)`, just like in the code, so in my examples, it just says that, for example 1, `23` is in `1234`, while in example 2, `44` is not in `76384`. And yeah, I figured that using recursion in this problem is hard, but we'll get a zero grade if we don't use recursion so we have no choice :(

Comment: I think what's you're looking for is `str(x)` compare with `str(y)` as @ggorlen suggested. Because number can only be compared with ordinal values.

Comment: @DanielHao how can I use that in a recursive code?

Comment: @starshine look at my answer, there you have it

Comment: @Morinator thank you! I'm adding it to my code now and I'll update you if it works correctly ^u^

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation that works for inputs of any size. We can use [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to form logical structure of our program -

```py
def int_check(whole, part):
  if whole < part:
    return False                        # base case: w < p
  elif whole % e(part) == part:
    return True                         # induction: w >= p
  else:
    return int_check(whole // 10, part) # induction: w >= p, w % e(p) != p

def e(n, m = 10):
  if n < 10:
    return m                            # base case: n < 10
  else:
    return e(n // 10, m * 10)           # induction: n >= 10
```

Here's a variation that does not need to compute a separate `e` (seen above). This has some similarity to @Morinator's technique but is careful to avoid bugs found in their answer -

```py
def int_check(whole, part):
  def loop (w, q):
    if q == 0:
      return True                        # base case: q == 0
    elif w < q:
      return False                       # induction: q > 0
    elif w % 10 == q % 10:
      return loop(w // 10, q // 10)      # induction: q > 0, w >= q
    else:
      return loop(w // 10, part)         # induction: q > 0, w >= q, w % 10 != q % 10
  return loop(whole, part)
```

Each implementation of `int_check` has the same output -

```py
print(int_check(1234567, 23))       # True
print(int_check(1234567, 456))      # True
print(int_check(1234567, 3))        # True
print(int_check(1234567, 123))      # True
print(int_check(1234567, 3456))     # True
print(int_check(1234567, 56))       # True
print(int_check(1234567, 1234567))  # True

print(int_check(1234567, 58))       # False
print(int_check(1234567, 125))      # False
print(int_check(1234567, 2347))     # False
print(int_check(1234567, 45679))    # False
print(int_check(1234567, 99))       # False
```

Comment: So the only change that was needed was another condition on when to return false? I already had something similar as a test, but I guess I was a little off. But nice to know that I wasnt far off.

Comment: @Morinator it's the `else intCheck(y // 10, x)` in your program where the bug exists. the problem is `x` is `x // 10` after `intCheck` recurs, so there's no way to go back and check the original `x` against `y // 10`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Note: In this solution, x needs to be contained as continuous subsequence, i.e. (123, 13) would evaluate to *False*.

```
def intCheck(y, x):
    if not 10 <= x <= 99:
        return "invalid"

    if y < 10:  # y is too small to contain x
        return False
    elif (y - x) % 100 == 0:  # x is contained in the last 2 digits of y
        return True
    else:
        return intCheck(y // 10, x)  # check if y is inside the other digits of y => remove last digit of y
```

Like the comment says though, you shouldn't use this function in real life.

Comment: Nice,  Will suggest to add this line first to check `x`: if 99 < x < 10: return 'Invalid' as the orig. PO stated?

Comment: yeah, i did that now

Comment: Hi! This works, however it doesn't work on **all** possibilities of `(y,x)` (based on what our school uses to check our codes).

Comment: Ok, can you give me an instance where it fails?

Comment: It doesn't tell us where it fails :( I guess it's up to the students to recheck it.

Comment: intCheck(2816, 28) should be True I think? And it evaluates to True in my IDE

Comment: I think it's in instances like this that fails: `(1783, 13)`

Comment: Yeah, of course it does. I didn't know that was supposed to be True :D

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to add that, I was also not sure at first it cases like that were True

Comment: Do the digits also need to be in the same order? E.g. is `x=13` in `y=321` accepted or not?

Comment: I left this answer because imo it provides value aswell. I posted a new answer fitting to the new problem description.

Comment: @ggorlen I don't think so :3

Answer (score 0):

```
def intCheck(y, x):
    if x == 0:
        return True
    if y == 0:
        return False

    return intCheck(y // 10, x // 10) if (y - x) % 10 == 0 else intCheck(y // 10, x)
```

This version works in all my tests, according to the new problem definition.

Comment: On the side: I think it would evaluate (1, 01) to True, even though it should be false. But as integers with leading 0 are illegal in Python, this shouldn't matter imo.

Comment: Needs debugging. returns `True` for `intCheck(1234567,125)` and `intCheck(1234567,2347)`

Comment: it's the `else intCheck(y // 10, x)` in your program where the bug exists. the problem is `x` is `x // 10` after `intCheck` recurs, so there's no way to go back and check the original `x` against `y // 10`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the last two digits match using a modulo 100 on N. Then remove the last digit of N and repeat the process.  Continue until all digits have been checked:

```
def numContains(N,x,p10=10):
    if N<0:      return numContains(-N,x)       # remove sign from N
    if N<x:      return False                   # exhausted digits of N
    if p10<=x:   return numContains(N,x,p10*10) # find right decimal scale
    if N%p10==x: return True                    # x matches ending digits
    return numContains(N//10,x,p10)             # remove last digit

print(numContains(12345,23))      # True
print(numContains(76384, 44))     # False
print(numContains(7612384, 123))  # True
print(numContains(-7612384, 123)) # True
```

If non-consecutive digits (in same order) are eligible, then the function can be altered to remove ending digits at each position within the decimal scale of x:

```
def numContains(N,x,p10=10):
    if N<0:      return numContains(-N,x)       # remove sign from N
    if N<x:      return False                   # exhausted digits of N
    if p10<=x:   return numContains(N,x,p10*10) # find right decimal scale
    if N%p10==x: return True                    # x matches ending digits
    t=1                
    while t<p10:                                # within range of x's scale       
        left,right = divmod(N,t)                # remove digit near end
        if numContains(left//10*t+right,x,p10): # try with that
            return True
        t *= 10
    return False

print(numContains(7612384, 134)) # True
print(numContains(7612384, 143)) # False
print(numContains(17633333000842222, 134)) # True
```

Comment: the fixed `100` constrains the inputs to certain sizes. make it work for `N` and `x` of any size

Comment: question also asks for a recursive implementation

Comment: @Thankyou, I missed the "recursive" requirement. I guess it wasn't bold enough :) There you go.